# How to display select options inside an accordion in Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to use the Bootstrap Select plugin inside of a Bootstrap 32 accordion ([see this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/52VtD/3385/)) but the Select option is hiding inside the `panel-body`:

```
<div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <select class="selectpicker">
            <option>Mustard</option>
            <option>Ketchup</option>
            <option>Relish</option>
        </select>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem the position of the dropdown list.

**fiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/3386/

Just add a class on your dropdown list to make is position relative.

```
.bootstrap-select .dropdown-menu{
    position:relative;
}
```